# Pandas How to replace all rows in certain columns without affecting the others?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master Dataframe (df_a) with columns a-b-c-d-e. I have a second Dataframe (df_b) with new info that updates the values in columns a-b-c.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    'c': [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'd': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
    'e': ['bar','bar','bar','bar','bar','bar']
})

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a': [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
    'c': [3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
})

df_a:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   foo bar
1   0   0   0   foo bar
2   0   0   0   foo bar
3   0   0   0   foo bar
4   0   0   0   foo bar
5   0   0   0   foo bar

df_b:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   0   0   0
2   2   2   2
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
5   0   0   0

Desired output: 
df_a_new:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   foo bar
1   0   0   0   foo bar
2   2   2   2   foo bar
3   0   0   0   foo bar
4   0   0   0   foo bar
5   0   0   0   foo bar
```

The indexes will always be the same, so I typically would just use map() for single columns, but in my actual dataset there are 50 columns I have to update and it would not be as efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic solution would look like :

Either  find the difference of columns from `df_a` and `df_b` then assign them to `df_b`

```
df_b.assign(**df_a.loc[:,df_a.columns.difference(df_b.columns,sort=False)])
```

Or another way:

```
df_b.combine_first(df_a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use an OR `|` operator between the 2 dataset.  `df_b|df_a[df_b.columns]` basically considers 0 as False and returns non zero values for rows (if equivalent rows have values, then it prioritizes the first) -

```
df_a[df_b.columns] = df_a[df_b.columns] | df_b
print(df_a)
```

```
   a  b  c    d    e
0  1  2  3  foo  bar
1  0  0  0  foo  bar
2  2  2  2  foo  bar
3  0  0  0  foo  bar
4  0  0  0  foo  bar
5  0  0  0  foo  bar
```

Comment: This works if OP actually looking to update the **zero values only**. If `df_a` contains non-zero values that need to be update, this will fail.

Comment: Based on what OP wants to do, they want to choose filled rows from both datasets and combine them. Thats why I also mention that if both have corresponding rows filled, only one would get filled, it wouldnt work. OP has not mentioned what would be the expectation during that case. Thanks for adding the comment to point this out!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `concat()` method:-

```
pd.concat((df_b,df_a[df_a.columns[3:]]),axis=1)
```

Here `df_a.columns[3:]` gives `Index(['d', 'e'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
df_a_new = df_a.iloc[:]
df_a_new.iloc[:,:3] = df_b.iloc[:,:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is `combine_first`, which returns **a new dataframe**:

```
df_b.combine_first(df_a)
```

Or inplace change with `update`:

```
df_a.update(df_b)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c    d    e
0  1  2  3  foo  bar
1  0  0  0  foo  bar
2  2  2  2  foo  bar
3  0  0  0  foo  bar
4  0  0  0  foo  bar
5  0  0  0  foo  bar
```